# How to write this SQL against PG?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say, there is a table A, with columns `a` and `b`, both are `int` type with unique index.

I want to select from `A` where

- if there a tuple whose `a` equal to 100, then return this tuple
- otherwise, return a tuple whose `b` is smallest and less than 10000

This can be easily done with two SQL statements:

```sql
select * from A where a = 100
```

If first SQL returns nothing, then run:

```sql
select * from A where b < 10000 order by b limit 1
```

But I want to implement this logic in a single SQL statement. Is it possible?

Comment: So, `a` is not unique and `b` is not unique, but `(a,b)` is unique? And there are three cases: **(1)** Rows with `a = 100` exist: return those rows. **(2)** Rows with `a = 100` do not exist and the minimum `b` in the table is < 10000: return the row(s) with that minimum `b`. **(3)** Rows with `a = 100` do not exist and the minimum `b` in the table is >= 10000: return no rows. Correct?

Comment: Or `a` is unique and `b` is unique. And there are three cases: (1) A Row with `a = 100` exists: return that row. (2) A row with `a = 100` does not exist and the minimum `b` in the table is < 10000: return the row with that minimum `b`. (3) A row with `a = 100` does not exist and the minimum `b` in the table is >= 10000: return no rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Both `a` and `b` are unique. You may consider the two columns are independent.

Comment: Why do you need a single statement? If the reason is not to have the client application do the logic, you can use a function or call a block of code, starting your query with  DO $$, ecc....

Answer (score 3):

```
with a100orminb as
(
  select *, 1 as priority from A where a = 100
  union all
  select *, 2 as priority from A where b < 10000 order by b limit 1
)
select * from a100orminb order by priority limit 1;
```

You'll get unneeded column "priority", if you don't want to list all columns in the SQL, and use `*`, but I suppose that it is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want that to be one statement, but `UNION ALL`, sorting and a `LIMIT` should do the trick:

```
(SELECT *, FALSE AS differs_from_100
FROM a WHERE a = 100
UNION ALL
SELECT *, TRUE AS differs_from_100
FROM a WHERE b < 10000)
ORDER BY differs_from_100, b
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

The disadvantage is that you have to execute the second statement even if the first returns a result, so running two statements might be preferable.

A more complicated version that might perform better would be

```
WITH has_100 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM a WHERE a = 100
)
SELECT * FROM has_100
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM a WHERE b < 10000
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM has_100)
ORDER BY b
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I wonder if it makes a difference in performance if the second query used `and not exists (select * from a where a = 100)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good idea, I have added an attempt for that.